# can not addthis share button in wordpress blog button in fishpig magento extension

Tags: php, wordpress, magento-1.8, addthis

I have installed fishpig magento wordpress integration extension. 
It is working fine for blog. but i want to put addthis social media  buttons blog details page.

I have tried install extenstion of addthis in wordpress but its not working. but on simple product page of magento it is working.

Now when  i tried to debug it i got path of plugin where blog come the file is here

```
"/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wordpress/post/view.phtml"
```

where  i added code of addthis

```
  <div class="addthis_responsive_sharing"></div>
```

and also include jquery in magento header file

```
<script type="text/javascript"       src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-54e8ae370e853a28" async="async"></script>
```

but its not working. can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You only need the addthis_widget.js once. You should remove this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>
```

Also, because the Responsive Sharing Buttons are AddThis Pro tools you'll need to make sure the domain that you're using is enabled on the billing page of the AddThis dashboard.